# ng-class updates all items in ng-repeat in AngularJs view when class is changed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to apply AngularJs' `ng-class` only to the specific item that is clicked, but no matter where I put the `ng-class="class"`, each time the class gets updated, it is applied to all items in the `ng-repeat` directive.

**Interesting**: I would have thought that adding it with `data-target="#collapse_{{ $index }}` would only change the corresponding item with the same $index? :(

What am I doing wrong?

**How can I have the class change only apply to the specific item that was clicked?** I want to create something where a user can select and un-select a line.

Here is a very similar post, but I am not sure how to implement this according to my needs: [Only add class to specific ng-repeat in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370325/only-add-class-to-specific-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)

**He is my basic HTML for my header I want to change:**

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="container-fluid panel-container item-container">
        <div class="col-xs-1 text-left">
            <h4>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_{{ $index }}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 text-left product-header">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_{{ $index }}">
                <span>Product Name: {{product.productName}}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            <span class="panel-title btn-group">
                <button type="button" id="button-selected" class="btn btn-default btn-sm abc" ng-click="addProduct(product)" ng-class="class">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-primary"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
.active-product {
    background: red;
    color: green;
}

.inactive-product {
    background: none;
    color: none;
}
```

**Here is my controller method (it is called by the `addProduct` function):**

```
$scope.class = "inactive-product";

function changeClass() {
    if ($scope.class === "active-product")
        $scope.class = "inactive-product";
    else
        $scope.class = "active-product";
};
```

This is an example how every item gets changed:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `$scope.class`, so it makes sense that every element is using it. You may need one `class` property on each product:

Template:

```
ng-class="product.class"
```

Controller:

```
function changeClass(product) {
    if (product.class === "active-product")
        product.class = "inactive-product";
    else
        product.class = "active-product";
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Quite logical when you think of it. You really helped me loads! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Can there be only one active item at a time? If so, you might only need to store the index of the active item. I can update my answer if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are updating the class of all the elements in the array, so what you could do to resolve this issue is put a ng-click event that toggle a extra property and indicates if the current object is selected

```
<div ng-repeat='item in productList' >
   <p ng-class='item.selected ? "active" : "default"' ng-click='toggleActive($index)'>item.id</p>
</div>
```

Finally in the controller one function that based on the **index** or another **property** if you prefer, change the selected attribute

```
$scope.toggleActive = function (){
 //Makes only the clicked object have      the selected attribute in true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Also a great solution.